# Making great 3D games with HTML only, is that possible?

Tags: html

Please I want examples
Is that possible or impossible?
Also, is it possible to explain the benefit of the html language in games and what is the best game that can be made using html only without css or javascript
Thank you so much for all the great help!

Comment: With just HTML? No.

Comment: Imagine building a house. HTML is the boards and nails, CSS is the paint and states (on/off), and javascript is the electricity and water. Can you make something interactive with just boards?

Comment: You might be able to create some sort of choose-your-own-adventure type game in HTML, but without any scripted interactivity it wouldn't be very engaging. In any case, your question is off-topic. Voting to close, sorry

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You need to use atleast CSS to make games. Canvas can be used to draw graphics but it's a mix of HTML and JS. SVG can also be used which can be easily embedded into HTML, but a separate language.